# What are artifacts in truffle?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, truffle

Your build artifacts are saved within the `./build` directory, along side the compiled deployed contract artifacts in `./build/contracts`.

What exactly are these artifacts?

Answer (score 7):

It saves the ABI, application binary interface of the contract and other info related to the contract. Open the contract_name.json in the ./build/contracts you can see all the information about the contract. If you want to deploy the contract again, then you don't have to compile it again, the contract bytecode from the contract_name.json file will be used.

Comment: Is there a way to replace those artifacts with the ones generated by Remix IDE?

Comment: So you could say... artifacts are compiled contracts?

Comment: Yeah, but what is an artifact, I beleive the question is still not answered.

Answer (score 6):

The more comprehensive explanation can be found here: [What are Artifacts](https://trufflesuite.github.io/artifact-updates/background.html#what-are-artifacts)

In short, *truffle artifact is a JSON bundle that contains a lot of useful information related to a contract like the ABI, the contract bytecode, the deployment details, compiler version, etc...*

Answer (score 1):

Artifacts are simply the JSON files of the contracts. the meaning of artifact in software is anything that is created so a piece of software can be developed.