# what is the difference between .json files and .metadata.json files in the artifacts folder in remix?

Tags: contract-development, remix, abi

From [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/36523/44794), I have read that:

> artifacts saves the ABI, binary of contract and other info related to
> the contract.

In Remix when I open the artifacts folder I see a `.json` and a `.metadata.json` file. What is the difference between these two files and what purpose does each serve?