# How do I dynamically set in my Web3.js file the deployed smart contract's ABI & address?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ganache

I'm using Truffle, Solidity, Web3.js, and Ganache. Whenever I deploy a smart contract, I have to copy and paste the new ABI & address of the contract. How can I dynamically change the value so that every time a new smart contract is deployed it saves me from having to copy and paste these new values into my .js file?

Comment: Truffle generates a .json file when a contract is deployed. From that file you can extract the contract abi and the address deployed, see this question for location https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/30457/what-are-artifacts-in-truffle.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I'm aware that I can manually extract it this way. But what I want to know is if there's a way to automate it so that whenever a new contract is deployed, I won't have to go into the .json file and copy and paste it every time. Is there a way I can import it with code?

Comment: It is possible but requires some work. In the backend from javascript you can require the JSON file and then use TruffleContract to get the deployed instance. From client side either make the JSON available from an endpoint or from the migrations scripts trigger a rebuild of your source.

Comment: Are you able to answer the question with an example of you doing that? It would help me out a lot and anyone else struggling with this. :)

Comment: Better, Truffle has several examples projects, for example https://github.com/truffle-box/webpack-box. If you look at client code [`index.js`](https://github.com/truffle-box/webpack-box/blob/master/app/src/index.js) it imports the contract artifact `import metaCoinArtifact from "../../build/contracts/MetaCoin.json"` directly from the truffle output.

Comment: BRO THANK YOU!!!!! This is exactly what I was looking for! You're awesome thank you so much!!!! Seriously this is exactly the answer to my question! Damn I'm so happy lol thank you!!

Comment: Great! If you have some time it will be nice if you add an example as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

artifacts.require("<contract_name>") will fetch the contracts json file(which is generated in build folder after compiling every time) within truffle project.